# How to add list of treeset values to a json array in java

Tags: java

I have the below list of elements.

```
[ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ]
```

I want to return the values as a json array as below:

```
{
    "cars": [ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ]
}
```

Can some one please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you want to put the JSON like this.
Anyhow looks like for this case, you can create a POJO(Plain old java object) by naming Cars.
Next you can iterate the TreeSet and create a collection of Cars and can convert to JSON.
I think you will get the proper results.

The following link might help you if you need to do some custom JSON: [GSON: Serialize object with java.util.TreeSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32945979/gson-serialize-object-with-java-util-treeset)